# using custom actionbar height on android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My question is not about how but is it OK to use a custom size for actionbar from the perspective of future releases of Android ?

Could using a custom size break the product in future releases ? or need more testing now and future ? What kind of things should I think of, before using a custom size ?

Our designer is iOS guy and is giving me designs with thin actionbar as in iOS. I want to know any technical reasons to use standard size before pushing back.

appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no problem.
The ActionBar is now customizable with Toolbar. And Toolbar has been added to support library (which indicates that it's probably going to be used widely).

But as in if it's OK design-wise, you can take a look at Material Design specs to get more information.